# Android selectableItemBackground background tint

Tags: android

When building my layout, I noticed that the background color of the `selectableItemBackground` does not match the background color of the rest of the UI. To mitigate this, I wanted to import `{android_sdk}/platforms/{platform}/data/res/drawable/item_background.xml`. Then of course I need to import the related drawables as well, however, the drawables `@drawable/list_selector_background_disabled` and `@drawable/list_selector_background_focused` are not in the drawable folder as I would expect.

So my question is either: Where are these drawables located? Or: How do I change the background tint of the default `selectableItemBackground`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `android:foreground` property for selectableItemBackground, which enables you use `android:background` and tint for any control

```
 android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
```